# Random Forest classification not in R

Tags: qgis, arcmap, software-recommendations, random-forest

I had previously used ENVI to create ROIs for a Random Forest classification. After creating my files in ENVI, I exported these to EnMap and ran the classification there. (Please note knowledge of EnMap is not required to answer this question)

To rerun my results, I created tifs of the satellite data (SPOT 6) & training & test datasets, as this is required for EnMap - or so I thought. I tried to use EnMap again to run my results however I keep getting error messages. After much detective work, I have concluded the reason the software was reluctant to run the classification was because files are not in in ENVI format and tif and bsq just will not do.

I no longer have access to ENVI so cannot convert my files to the ENVI file type for use in EnMap. I do not currently know anyone else with the software who could help. I'm therefore looking for an alternative way to run an RF classification.

I have access to ArcMap and QGIS and am fairly competent with both. I'd be willing to download new software to try however I live in a remote area with limited internet and many freeware cannot be easily learnt in a short space of time, especially when there is no one around to help teach it, as is the case for my situation. So I'm not sure R is an option. I'd still be ok with using EnMap if I could get it to work.

Comment: Did you tried [SNAP](http://step.esa.int/main/toolboxes/snap/)? It has a Random Forest module. It isn't for Sentinel use only.

Comment: How far did you get when you tried using QGIS or ArcGIS for Desktop?  For focussed Q&A it is best to describe precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck using a single product. If you get no or inadequate answers then you can always ask about the other in a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

1)

> Random Forest classification not in R

You don't know R. R is Open Source with many many books and tutorials to learn it and a strong support from the R community.

I use generally first the [sos](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sos/index.html) package in the R shell to find packages which have Random Forest Classification functions

```
library(sos)
# find packages with Random Forest Classification functions
unique(findFn("Random Forest Classification")$Package)
...
found 330 matches;  retrieving 17 pages
Downloaded 326 links in 131 packages.
[1] "ggRandomForests"      "bigrf"                "randomForestSRC"     
[4] "vegclust"             "randomUniformForest"  "CORElearn"           
[7] "randomForest"         "vita"                 "MAclinical"          
[10] "OTE"                  "rfPermute"            "caret"               
[13] "RRF"                  "SSDM"                 "snpRF"               
[16] "forestFloor"          "mlDNA"                "fuzzyforest"         
[19] "rfUtilities"          "ModelMap"             "TDMR"                
....
[130] "xgboost"
```

And you can find examples in GIS SE as [How to utilise single 'randomForest' model for several rasters in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/59588/2581) (there are others)  and general articles as [unsupervised classification with R](http://remote-sensing.eu/unsupervised-classification-with-r/) or [Image Classification with RandomForests in R (and QGIS)](http://amsantac.co/blog/en/2015/11/28/classification-r.html) witch provides a .rsx script for the QGIS Processing Toolbox ([rf_image_classification.rsx](https://gist.github.com/amsantac/5183c0c71a8dcbc27a4f))

2) You can also use the Orfeo scripts in the Processing Toolbox [QGIS - OTB - Image classification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQjKavMUHqw)
3) And Python has modules for that ([Chapter 5: Classification of land cover](http://ceholden.github.io/open-geo-tutorial/python/chapter_5_classification.html))

Therefore, there are alternative solutions, but I am well aware that you must learn them (scripts and not point-and-click interfaces)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to run it in Arc in the end
With regards to QGIS, I couldn't get the Orfeo toolbox to appear in the Processing options menu